# Double Slit Experiment question regarding an observation doesn't seem to collapse the wave function

Tags: double-slit-experiment

During the double slit experiment, when we see interference on the screen that shows the light as a wave, why doesn't it become a particle as soon as it interact with the screen?  Wouldn't this be the same as the delayed observation experiment where they put a detector behind the slit and caused  the light to become a particle and thus does not create interference?

Comment: The pattern on the screen does not "show the light as a wave." It shows the spatial distribution of the _particles_ that interact with the screen. The "wave" appears in mathematical equations that predict that distribution. The question of why things that interact in a particle like way are distributed according to wave mechanics is kind of the spooky heart of quantum physics.

Comment: There is no such thing as wave function collapse.

Comment: @SolomonSlow i thought if the particle is observed even after it has passed through the slit, it still does not cause an interference pattern. Then by the same token, if the screen at the end which observes(interact) with the particle, shouldn't it also not show an interference pattern?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the particle." If just one particle makes it through the slits, then you will get just one pixel, recorded in your image. (assuming a digital detector.) You must record at least a thousand or so individual particles (each one painting a distinct "point" on the picture) before the diffraction pattern begins to emerge. Tens of thousands is better. https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.4955173

Comment: Also, not sure what you think "observed" means, but the interaction with the screen _is_ the observation. When it hits the screen, you get to know at what _point_ it hit. Before it hits the screen, you don't know anything except the wave function, which depends only on the geometry of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Light exhibits wave-particle duality. The light possesses characteristics of both the wave and the particle at any time, and thus interpreting the light as being converted from the wave to a particle is misleading.
2. The interference pattern in the double-slit experiment appears since the path of the light before it reaches the screen (i.e., whether they passed through the upper slit or the lower slit) is undetermined. As far as we don't make an observation near the slits to determine the path of the light, the interference pattern on the screen will not disappear.